# SQLAlchemy self-referencing m2m works only one direction

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a question regarfing m2m to itself being symmettrical.

```py
class Strike(UpdatedAtMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'strikes'

    id: Mapped[BigIntPk]
    duration: Mapped[Range[datetime.datetime] | None] = mapped_column(
        TSTZRANGE(),
    )
    planned_on_date: Mapped[datetime.date | None]
    goals: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text())
    results: Mapped[str | None] = mapped_column(Text())
    overall_num_of_employees_involved: Mapped[int]
    enterprise_id: Mapped[BigIntType] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('enterprises.id'),
    )
    created_by_id: Mapped[BigIntType] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('users.id'),
    )
    union_in_charge_id: Mapped[BigIntType | None] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('unions.id', ondelete='SET NULL'),
    )
    group: Mapped[list['Strike']] = relationship(
        'Strike',
        secondary=StrikeToItself.__table__,
        passive_deletes=True,
        primaryjoin='Strike.id==StrikeToItself.strike_left_id',
        secondaryjoin='Strike.id==StrikeToItself.strike_right_id',
    )
```

Table above  represents a strike and it has a m2m to itself property / relationship called **group** that represents group of strikes via intermediate table as it shown bellow:

```py
class StrikeToItself(CreatedAtMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'strike_to_itself_associations'

    strike_left_id: Mapped[BigIntType] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('strikes.id', ondelete='CASCADE', ),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    strike_right_id: Mapped[BigIntType] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('strikes.id', ondelete='CASCADE', ),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(
            strike_left_id != strike_right_id,
            name='left_ne_right',
        ),
    )
```

Problem i have with this configuration is like that:

[image]

Lets say we have 2 strikes in one group 160 and 164

if i query group for strike 160

```py
s = await session.get(Strike, 160)
await s.awaitable_attrs.group
->>>[Strike 164 on enterprise 13]
```

i would get related group of strikes - all correct, but if i query group for strike 164 i would get nothing instead of Strike 160.
This is not a surprise due to a sql being emmited

```
2023-07-18 12:13:16,526 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT strikes.id AS strikes_id, strikes.duration AS strikes_duration, strikes.planned_on_date AS strikes_planned_on_date, strikes.goals AS strikes_goals, strikes.results AS strikes_results, strikes.overall_num_of_employees_involved AS strikes_overall_num_of_employees_involved, strikes.enterprise_id AS strikes_enterprise_id, strikes.created_by_id AS strikes_created_by_id, strikes.union_in_charge_id AS strikes_union_in_charge_id, strikes.updated_at AS strikes_updated_at 
FROM strikes, strike_to_itself_associations 
WHERE $1::BIGINT = strike_to_itself_associations.strike_left_id AND strikes.id = strike_to_itself_associations.strike_right_id
2023-07-18 12:13:16,526 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 102.8s ago] (164,)
```

Seems like insead of forming a join it just loads both tables and tries to match primary keys from them.
Question is - how to define `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` conditions in order to make Alchemy use regular join?
DB - Postgres 15

Thank you.